# System DSN command prompt

Tags: odbc, dsn

I can create a System DSN connection via the following command:

> odbcconf.exe /a {CONFIGSYSDSN "SQL Server"
>   "DSN=NAME|Description=DESCRIPTION|SERVER=MYSQLSERVER|Trusted_Connection=Yes|Database=DBNAME"}

I need to create it with an specific option, but I can't find it anywere: establishing the language for SQL Server system messages to Spanish

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: I'm trying this on both x86 and x64, doing this on the system32 or the syswow64 folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That parameter you are looking for is: `LANGUAGE=Espanol`

Or you can use gui tool `odbcad32.exe`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I was looking for!!
I tried with Language=Spanish, ES, ES_ES, and so others.
The correct one is: Language=Español

Comment: If you'll need another languages or options, use that `odbcad32` GUI to create File DSN, then you can read parameters from that file.

Answer (score 1):

usually they end up in ControlPanel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC) on Windows systems.

Comment: Yes I know, but I need this via command line because I have to reproduce in more than 40 computers.